# WebException was caught When Consuming RSS Feed on ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, xml-parsing, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I want to consume my blog's RSS feed from other asp.net site. I can't get rss data. I try different methods (like HttpWebRequest) for consuming RSS feed but I always get same error.

```
WebException was caught.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred during an import operation.
```

What was the problem ?

feed address: http://blog.melihmucuk.com/feed/
I need post title, link and posted date.

for example :

```
Try

            Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("http://blog.melihmucuk.com/feed/")
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
            ds.ReadXml(reader) // incorrect line

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

I think, that's a simple task, but I don't know what is the problem.

Also I try this:

```
Try
            Dim title As String
            Dim link As String
            Dim description As String
            Dim reader = XmlReader.Create("http://blog.melihmucuk.com/feed/")//incorrect line

            Dim feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader)

            For Each item In feed.Items
                title = item.Title.Text
                link = item.Links(0).Uri.ToString
            Next

            HyperLink1.Text = title
            HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = link
            Label1.Text = description

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this out:-

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class Reader
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Dim rssFeed = New Uri("http://blog.melihmucuk.com/feed/")

            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(rssFeed)
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

            Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Dim xdoc As XDocument = New XDocument()
                xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader)

                'Read the nodes and display as per your requirement.
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Also add this block in your web.config file:-**

```
<configuration>
   <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy usesystemdefault="true"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: I have a wordpress web site and this is the my feed address: [RSS Address](http://blog.melihmucuk.com/feed/) how can I consume this feed?

Comment: @MelihMucuk Try this updated one. And please let me know in case if you are still facing any issues.

Comment: Still I'm getting same error. `Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()` this is the incorrect line. Error: WebException was caught.

Comment: I can't add `usesystemdefault="true"` to web.config file. Error: [link](http://melihmucuk.com/images/proxy.png)

Comment: No, I don't get build errors. But still I get same error at same line. `Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()` Error: WebException was caught.